# Can one run Mathematica 11 on macOS Catalina using Retroactive?

Tags: mac-os-x, compatibility, version-11

I know that only Mathematica 12+ runs on macOS Catalina. 
However some apps that supposedly do not work (like Aperture) can work using the *Retroactive* app.

Has anyone tried that? Successes?

Thanks

Comment: The blog post about Retroactive seems to say that the apps it supports are already 64-bit, except for a few components it can swap out. Mathematica 11's front end is 32-bit. It's not just a question of some minor components.